# Edit xltm file with macro without .vba file

Tags: excel, vba

I have been given a .xltm file which has template, data and macros. The earlier developer has lost the the .vba file. I wanted to debug and make changes in macro which automatically close excel the moment I open it. Stuggling to work arround the situation for last one week.

Is there any way, I can open the excel file without executing a macro and then edit and save them? What is the way as I don't have .vba file. Or is there any tool which can generate the .vba file from .xmlt and allow me to debug, edit and save in tool like Visula studio.

Help deperatly needed.

Comment: You've tagged this Excel and VBA.  In this context, there's no such thing as .xmlt or .vba.  Please clarify what files you actually have, and/or correct the Q tags

Comment: Corrected the extention to xltm. My bad. Well about vba, I have seen in my previous implementation that macros are maintained in the seperate .vba files. I read in some arcticles now it has been discontinued from quite few versions. Well need some way to edit macro before it execute.

Answer (score 0):

This will open the template in edit mode, and suppress any auto-run macros it might contain:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim z As Workbook, sec
    sec = Application.AutomationSecurity 'store current state
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    Set z = Workbooks.Open("C:\Excel\Temp\Tester.xltm", editable:=True)
    Application.AutomationSecurity = sec
End Sub
```

Not sure what you mean by ".vba file" though. VBA is embedded in the xltm file and is not editable seaprately from that file. You can't use VS to debug VBA code - you need to use the Excel VB editor for that.